# Vue router & firebase

Tags: vue.js, firebase, http-status-code-404, spa, vue-router

Добрый день.
В проекте используется Vue.js + vue-router
Когда я делаю deploy на хостинг firebase. Все страницы, если обновить окно браузера попадают на страницу 404.
Как это можно исправить ?

Comment: а оно у вас хоть немного то работает?

Comment: Там уже всё починил. Но у меня вопрос сейчас по firebase другой.

Я хочу подключить авторизацию и базу данных импортами.

Но так как я здесь привожу пример не подключается.
Сборщики не используются. (с Web Pack всё естественно работает) 

Я взял js с официального сайта. Скопировал в свой проект и попробовал подключить.

import firebase from '/node_modules/firebase/app'